# Wordpress javascript works how?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Folks,

I am new to wordpress. I am converting a html template to wordpress.
THE script is this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

And the javascript functions are:

```
<script>
  var nice = false;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    nice = $("html").niceScroll();
  });

  var obj = window;//$(window);

  console.log(obj.length);
  console.log("selector" in obj);

</script>

<script>

  function toCell(px,py,ok) {
    $("#tab1").find('tr').eq(py).find('td').eq(px).addClass((ok)?'testok':'testko');
  };

  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#div1").html($("#div1").html()+' '+nice.version);
    $("#div2").html($("#div2").html()+' '+navigator.userAgent);

    toCell(1,1,nice.detected.ismozilla);

    toCell(2,1,(nice.detected.prefixstyle=='-webkit-'));

    toCell(3,1,nice.detected.isie);
    toCell(3,2,nice.detected.isie10);
    toCell(3,3,nice.detected.isie9);
    toCell(3,4,nice.detected.isie8);
    toCell(3,5,nice.detected.isie7);
    toCell(3,6,nice.detected.isieold);

    toCell(4,1,nice.detected.isopera);

    toCell(5,1,nice.detected.isios);
    toCell(5,2,nice.detected.isios4);

    toCell(0,8,nice.detected.cantouch);
    toCell(3,8,nice.detected.hasmstouch);

    toCell(1,10,nice.detected.hastransform);
    toCell(1,11,nice.detected.hastranslate3d);
    toCell(2,10,nice.detected.hastransition);
    toCell(2,11,!!nice.detected.transitionend);
    toCell(3,10,nice.hasanimationframe);
    toCell(3,11,nice.hascancelanimationframe);

    toCell(1,12,nice.detected.hasmousecapture);
    toCell(2,12,((nice.detected.cursorgrabvalue!='')&&(nice.detected.cursorgrabvalue.substr(0,3)!='url')));


  });

</script>
```

I know about registering, enqueuing but how will it can be transformed into wordpress theme.

Explain

Comment: It looks like this code generates a compatibility table? Where exactly do you want div1 and div2 to be, header or footer, or somewhere within one page?

Comment: Worth pointing out that a version of jQuery is registered in Wordpress by default.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can include JavaScript files in the `<head>` just like you would on a normal website. but `registering` and `enqueuing` is the preferred mechanism for WordPress.

You could also put your `<script>` directly in the `header.php` which would make it available on all pages. However, I would strongly suggest you make it an external script.

Depending on how you enqueue the the file, it will be added to your site header or footer with `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` respectively.